# Properly use JWT with Angular 2

Tags: php, angular, authentication, jwt

I have a working backend JWT setup on my PHP server, and I have finally after many hours gotten a result to log in console for angular, what I cant figure out now is how to manage this result and wait for the information to load to return a result, if I remove my subscribe function I cannot even render results which confuses me, Why cannot I simply use map?

Anyway here is my login function:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
        let result = false;
        var postData = "email=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        let headers: Headers;
        headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        this.http.post('https://callum.tech/jwt/', postData, {headers: headers})
            .take(1)
            .map((res:any) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data.token)
                    if (data.token) {
                        console.log("token exists");
                        // set token property
                        this.token = data.token;

                        // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: data.token }));
                        result = true;
                    }
                },
                err => {console.log(err)}
                //,() => console.log("done!?")
            );
        console.log(result);
        return Observable.of(result);
    }
```

Now this will login with the correct information (I return a json in PHP under 'token' and there are no issues, this is shown in the console)

[image]

I am not sure how to wait, and get the proper response, the POST stuff seems to be really sensitive to having subscription etc or it wont post data, so I am not sure how to deal with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.map` just maps the resolved response, it will not start the request. You always need to use `subscribe` to start it. That's the way how observables work.

Also the code is asynchronous, you can not do the `console.log(result);` at the end of your snippet, that line will be ran immediately after creating the observable via `this.http.post()...`.

See the docs for more information:

https://angular.io/guide/http

https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables